# Find all duplicate subdirectories in directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, recursion

I need to make a shell script that "lists all identical sub-directories (recursively) under the current working directory."

I'm new to shell scripts. How do I approach this?

To me, this means:

- for each directory starting in some starting directory, compare it to every other directory it shares by name.

  - if the other directory has the same name, check size.

    - if same size also, recursively compare contents of each directory item by item, maybe by `md5sum`(?) and continuing to do so for each subdirectory within the directories (recursively?)
- then, continue by recursively calling this on every subdirectory encountered
- then, repeat for every other directory in the directory structure

It would have been the most complicated program I'd have ever written, so I assume I'm just not aware of some shell command to do most of it for me?

I.e., how should I have approached this? All the other parts were about googling until I discovered the shell command that did it 90% of it for me.

(For a previous assignment that I wasn't able to finish, took a zero on this part, need to know how to approach it in the future.)

Comment: Sample input and output?

Comment: none given, i assume the input is the current working directory and the output is a list of directories considered identical. Sorry, can't be more specific

Comment: depends on how specifically you mean duplicate. does `dir1/file{1,2,3}` vs `dir2/file{1.2,3}` where `file{1,2,3}` are the same count as a duplicate? Note the dir1/dir2 are different. AND what about if `dir2/file{1,2,3}` is 3 levels down, does that count as a match against the same files in the original `dir1`? Lots of possibilities here and the learning opportunity may be in "how do you nail down a proper specification for what needs to be considered a dupe (and why)?". Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised to hear that there is a special Unix tool or special usage of a standard Unix tool to do exactly what you describe.  Maybe your understanding of the task is more complex than what the task giver intended.  Maybe with "identical" something concerning linking was meant.  Normally, hardlinking directories is not allowed, so this probably also isn't meant.

Anyway, I'd approach this task by creating checksums for all nodes in your tree, i. e. recursively:

- For a directory take the names of all entries and their checksums (recursion) and compute a checksum of them,
- for a plain file compute a checksum of its contents,
- for symlinks and special files (devices, etc.) consider what you want (I'll leave this out).

After creating checksums for all elements, search for duplicates (by sorting a list of all and searching for consecutive lines).

A quick solution could be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirchecksum() {
  if [ -f "$1" ]
  then
    checksum=$(md5sum < "$1")
  elif [ -d "$1" ]
  then
    checksum=$(
      find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P " \( ! -path "$1" \) \
                -exec bash -c "dirchecksum {}" \; |
        md5sum
    )
  fi
  echo "$checksum"
  echo "$checksum $1" 1>&3
}
export -f dirchecksum

list=$(dirchecksum "$1" 3>&1 1>/dev/null)

lastChecksum=''
while read checksum _ path
do
  if [ "$checksum" = "$lastChecksum" ]
  then
    echo "duplicate found: $path = $lastPath"
  fi
  lastChecksum=$checksum
  lastPath=$path
done < <(sort <<< "$list")
```

This script uses two tricks which might not be clear, so I mention them:

- To pass a shell function to `find -exec` one can `export -f` it (done below it) and then call `bash -c ...` to execute it.
- The shell function has *two* output streams, one for returning the result checksum (this is via stdout, i. e. fd 1), and one for giving out each checksum found on the way to this (this is via fd 3).

The sorting at the end uses the list given out via fd 3 as input.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
$ find -type d -exec sh -c "echo -n {}\  ; sh -c \"ls -s {}; basename {}\"|md5sum " \; | awk '$2 in a {print "Match:"; print a[$2], $1; next} a[$2]=$1{next}'
Match:
./bar/foo ./foo
```

`find` all directories: `find -type d`, output:

```
.
./bar
./bar/foo
./foo
```

`ls -s {}; basename {}` will print the simplified directory listing and the basename of the directory listed, for example for directory `foo`: `ls -s foo; basename foo`

```
total 0
0 test
foo
```

Those will cover the files in each dir, their sizes and the dir name. That output will be sent to `md5sum` and that along the dir:

```
. 674e2573b49826d4e32dfe81d9680369  -
./bar 4c2d588c5fa9781ad63ad8e86e575e01  -
./bar/foo ff8d1569685be86366f18ea89851db35  -
./foo ff8d1569685be86366f18ea89851db35  -
```

will be sent to `awk`:

```
$2 in a {            # hash as array key
    print "Match:"   # separate hits in output
    print a[$2], $1  # print matching dirscompared to
    next             # next record
} 
a[$2]=$1 {next}      # only first match is stored and
```

Test dir structure:

```
$ mkdir -p test/foo; mkdir -p test/bar/foo; touch test/foo/test; touch test/bar/foo/test
$ find test/
test/
test/bar
test/bar/foo
test/bar/foo/test  # touch test
test/foo
test/foo/test      # touch test
```